# Restful AND SOAP webservice in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, jax-ws

We have got SOAP based webservices but we are thinking of using RESTFUL webservices as RESTFUL webservices are faster than the SOAP ones. Because of the compatibility we would like to keep the SOAP services as well so there would be two versions of a service: a SOAP based and a RESTFUL one. The service consumers could choose which one they would like to use.

My problem is that the RESTFUL webservices are webs applications so we have to pack them in WAR file but the JAX-WS must be put into JAR file so the endpoints of these two services would be completely different. However these two services belong to each other (they are the same service but the interfaces are different) so it would be reasonable to call them on the same endpoint.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Could I create a class which would be a RESTFUL and a SOAP service as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an ideal case for an ESB. You should have the actual service layer as it is, and expose the other format via the ESB.

Or you could expose both SOAP and REST based services to the public via the ESB, (which I prefer due to many of the extensibility and manageability purposes) and let the ESB talk to the actual services to respond from the format that the client prefers.

If you use an ESB like [UltraESB](http://www.adroitlogic.org) you could expose both SOAP and REST format of the service on the same endpoint, (URL) and the ESB will convert it to the relevant format before talking to the actual service, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks Ruwan for the answer. Unfortunately we can't introduce a full ESB solution now we need some framework which could do that. Perphaps Apache CXF is sufficient to me. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-and-jax-ws.html